# SQL, Add a column to 'View', Data binning

Tags: sql

I joined three tables and made a view. In this view I have a column with the name of `AGE`. Now I like to create another column Next to the AGE column, with the name of `Age_bin_10yr`,  which shows age binned into 10-year bins `(eg. “Ge15_Lt25”, “Ge25_Lt35”, “Ge35_Lt45”, “Ge45_Lt55”, “Ge55_Lt65”, “Ge65_Lt75”, “Ge75_Lt85”, etc)`. I don't know how to do that. I really appreciate your help. Many thanks.

Comment: At least show us your table structure?

Comment: Round(AGE / 10, 0)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Ali, did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use a `case` statement for that:

```
select *,
     case when age >= 15 and age < 25 then 'Ge15_Lt25'
          when age >= 25 and age < 35 then 'Ge25_Lt35'
          when age >= 35 and age < 45 then 'Ge35_Lt45'
          when age >= 45 and age < 55 then 'Ge45_Lt55'
          ...
     end as Age_bin_10yr
from yourview
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `age` column is of type `INT`:

```
SELECT
    'Ge'+CAST((age-5)/10 AS VARCHAR)+'5_Lt'+CAST((age-5)/10+1 AS VARCHAR)+'5' AS Age_bin_10yr,
    * -- the rest of the columns you need
FROM
    ... -- the rest of the view definition
```